# in rails json rendering, how to show a different key name for a particular attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongoid, render

I am using Mongoid as my backend and I am in need to return json with an "id" attribute instead of the default "_id" used by mongoid

for instance, I have now

```
[{
  "_id": "4f2d8b971773eb18e6000001",
  "name": "Scooter"
}, {
  "_id": "4f2d8d9f1773eb18fd000001",
  "name": "Coldplay"
}]
```

from a call to render:

```
  format.json { render :json => @groups, only:[:name, :_id] }
```

but need,

```
[{
  "id": "4f2d8b971773eb18e6000001",
  "name": "Scooter"
}, {
  "id": "4f2d8d9f1773eb18fd000001",
  "name": "Coldplay"
}]
```

Any shortcuts?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to add an attribute accessor for `_id` called just `id`, then this should be easily solved by overriding `as_json` in your model.

```
def id
  self._id
end

def as_json(options={})
  options.merge!(:except => :_id, :methods => :id)
  super(options)
end
```

**Update:** Made the override a bit more friendly to the parent method.